# save async function as a string or in a data structure to gets its text to show on my browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, http

Im trying to  GET /tweets?query=YOUR_STRING
This endpoint should get a string and return the 10 latest tweets from Twitter API.

I cant make the async function to show on my localhost.

what am I doing wrong?

```
const Twit = require('twit')
const notifier = require('node-notifier');
const open = require('open');
const http = require('http')
const path = require('path')
const os = require('os')
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

var T = new Twit({
  consumer_key:         apikey,
  consumer_secret:      apiSecretKey,
  access_token:         accessToken,
  access_token_secret:  accessTokenSecret,
});
const apikey = 'oassIPpuUqqfCri407vaWRB83'
const apiSecretKey = '1ceYohWwmQyaimX6TlzG7YdeOMfTKaIOGlxynY7QlUlKO5RSOy'
const accessToken = '1404495546358931460-K9WqJMxXq9Rc83mDMplxmaAJpbg62C'
const accessTokenSecret = 'E84yMWyP4uuOM4N1u96YQ1fKfcI72uzjymBO9cepvEltl'

var totalMemory = os.totalmem()
var freeMemory = os.freemem()
var osType = os.type()
var CPUusage = os.cpus()
let nowTweets = (async () => {
T.get('search/tweets', { q: 'since:now', count: 10 }, function(err, data, 
response) {
const tweets = data.statuses
.map(tweet => tweet.text)
console.log(tweets);
  })
})



app.get('/health',(req, res) => {
  res.send('Total Memory: ' + totalMemory + '\n' +
  'Free Memory: ' + freeMemory + '\n' +
  'OS: ' + osType + '\n' +
  'CPU usage: ' + CPUusage)
})

app.get('/tweets',(req, res) => {
  res.send('Tweets: ' +'\n' + nowTweets)
})
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
app.listen(port, () => console.log('Listening on port ${port}'))
```

Comment: not sure if those are real tokens, but you should sanitize your posts before submitting

Comment: they're no longer viable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like an asynchronous issue w/ your `nowTweets` function. Also, no sense of having `async` on it since its using callbacks. Updated code below

```
const Twit = require('twit')
const notifier = require('node-notifier');
const open = require('open');
const http = require('http')
const path = require('path')
const os = require('os')
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

var T = new Twit({
    consumer_key: apikey,
    consumer_secret: apiSecretKey,
    access_token: accessToken,
    access_token_secret: accessTokenSecret,
});
const apikey = 'oassIPpuUqqfCri407vaWRB83'
const apiSecretKey = '1ceYohWwmQyaimX6TlzG7YdeOMfTKaIOGlxynY7QlUlKO5RSOy'
const accessToken = '1404495546358931460-K9WqJMxXq9Rc83mDMplxmaAJpbg62C'
const accessTokenSecret = 'E84yMWyP4uuOM4N1u96YQ1fKfcI72uzjymBO9cepvEltl'

var totalMemory = os.totalmem()
var freeMemory = os.freemem()
var osType = os.type()
var CPUusage = os.cpus()

let nowTweets = (cb) => {
    T.get('search/tweets', { q: 'since:now', count: 10 }, function (err, data,response) {
        const tweets = data.statuses
            .map(tweet => tweet.text)
        console.log(tweets);
        cb(tweets)
    })
}

app.get('/health', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Total Memory: ' + totalMemory + '\n' +
        'Free Memory: ' + freeMemory + '\n' +
        'OS: ' + osType + '\n' +
        'CPU usage: ' + CPUusage)
})

app.get('/tweets', (req, res) => {
    nowTweets(tweets => {
        res.send('Tweets: ' + '\n' + tweets)
    })
})
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
app.listen(port, () => console.log('Listening on port ${port}'))
```

Comment: mind "marking as answer" so others may benefit